# A1278 13" MacBook Pro wake from sleep issue

Tags: sleep-wake, macbook-pro

MacBook Pro 13.3"  - Early 2010

A1278

2.66 Ghz

16 GB RAM

2 TB Hard Drive (1.75 TB available)

10.9.5 (because I like Mavericks, we're happy together)

The issue is that the MacBook Pro won't wake up if I have closed the lid. This does not happen if I reopen the lid within a few quick minutes, but after an extended time, an hour, overnight. The sleep indicator light sometimes pulsates; sometimes is lit but not pulsating, but either way, it indicates that the laptop is not completely shutdown. I have to reset SMC every time (or hold down the power button until it shuts down) and restart it to get it up and going.  (I have also reset the NVRAM, only because I was trying everything.  No change.)  Resetting the SMC is ineffective, as the issue returns every time I close the lid.  Disk Utility only shows the typical Safari permissions that need changing, as they always do.  Rebooting in Safe Mode doesn't prevent the issue from happening.  I have reset the PRAM and I have reinstalled the OS.

I always leave my MBP plugged in, because I do all my work right by an outlet, so I have the energy power adapter settings to never sleep for both display and computer.  I have "put hard drive to sleep" unchecked.  I do have "wake for network access" checked.  My battery settings are set to 3 hours (although I never unplug it) and again, "put hard drive to sleep" is unchecked.

I recently disabled hibernation because I suspected it might be stuck in safe sleep mode, but it had no effect.  I also made sure that lidwake is set to 1.  In fact, here is a paste from Terminal:

Battery Power       -1

AC Power        -1*

Currently in use:

womp                 1

halfdim              1

sms                  1

hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage

networkoversleep     0

disksleep            0

sleep                0

hibernatemode        0

ttyskeepawake        1

displaysleep         0

acwake               0

lidwake              1

The last thing I have done through Terminal is to set standby to 0, again with no change.  There are no magnets in my work space, so I don't suspect that sort of interference.  If I put the laptop to sleep by selecting that option from the apple menu, I can wake the computer up.  It really does seem to only fail to wake when I have closed the lid.

This is the only issue with my MacBook Pro when it is up and running; there are no display issues, etc.  I am wondering if there might be something "manual" going on, perhaps related to the lid itself?  I do know the display cable is housed in the hinge.  Other than that, I am at a loss and would appreciate any insight.  Thank you.

Comment: If I may just add; I gave some thought to my earlier observation that the "sleep indicator light sometimes pulsates; sometimes is lit but not pulsating".  This made me wonder what would happen if I manually put the laptop to sleep through the menu, wait until the light begins to  pulsate and only then, close the lid.  It does take the light a full minute or two to finally pulsate.  I tried this last night.  This morning, the laptop woke up when I opened the lid.  Apparently, simply closing the lid does not cause the MacBook to sleep.  Is this a setting I can address?  Thank you.